# How do I pass a variable value through?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For those who maybe more familiar with writing variables in AngularJs/Ionic 2, I kindly ask if you could provide me the solution I need to the following:

In my app.components file, I have the below which sets the sidemenu items. I've added the variables translatedPageA to each line:

```
appPages: PageInterface[] = [
  { title: translatedPageA, component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageAPage },
  { title: translatedPageB, component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageBPage },
  { title: translatedPageC, component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageCPage },
  { title: translatedPageD, component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageDPage }

];
```

and I need to pass some variables values into this:

```
{{'translatedPageA' | translate }}
```

As you can see, as this is contained in an expression is the reason why I cannot insert into another expression. So the solution is to pass through a variable first. How do I create this variable and where do I insert this?

I have tried:

```
var translatedPageA: {{'HOME' | translate }};
```

Comment: Any update on this? Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$translate.instant()`. This [AngularJS translation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) helper will allow you translate markers directly inside your controller.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {

    //translate inside controller with instant
    var PageInterface = [
        { title: $translate.instant('HOME'), component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageAPage },
        { title: $translate.instant('SIDEB'), component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageBPage },
        { title: $translate.instant('SIDEC'), component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageCPage },
        { title: $translate.instant('SIDED'), component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageDPage }
    ];  
});
```

---

An other approach is to parse your title value directly into you view. This could be done like the in this:

<kbd>**[`Demo fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/76zk6xyh/1/)**</kbd>

#### View

```
<div ng-repeat="interfaceItem in pageInterface">
  {{ interfaceItem.title | translate}}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {

    //translate inside controller with instant
    $scope.pageInterface = [
        { title: 'HOME' , component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageAPage },
        { title: 'SIDEB', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageBPage },
        { title: 'SIDEC', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageCPage },
        { title: 'SIDED', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageDPage }
    ];  
});
```

Comment: Thanks @lin really appreciate the responses. I am trying work this all out being a new to angular. The full code is this:

Comment: @bluewavestudio Your plnkr isnt complete/running and full of errors. Please check this working example. http://jsfiddle.net/76zk6xyh/1/

Comment: apologes for that and thanks for jsfiddle @lin. The way my sidemenu items titles are created are done in this file, so assuming all the changes have to be made here for the side menu items to be updated. Here is the file: any help would be so grateful. gist.github.com/bluewavestudio/bd8d9f1d3e104fb21c29aed2d22b1‌​b02 –

Comment: @bluewavestudio Please add your view file were the translation happends.